# Centering text in "textarea" but then typing from left when the user clicks inside it

Tags: html, textarea, center

I'm using a textarea element on my page, with a placeholder. Is it possible to align the placeholder text within the textarea to the center, but when the user clicks in the box, they begin writing from the left side, not the center?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the *pseudo* class `:focus` to apply css only when the `textarea` element is focused

Like this

```
textarea{
  text-align:center;
}

textarea:focus{
  text-align:left;
}
```

Fiddle to test:

```css
textarea{
  text-align:center;
}

textarea:focus{
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" placeholder="Input Your Text"></textarea>
```